# nestjs- Cannot up migrations with migrate-mongo

Tags: node.js, typescript, migration, es6-modules, migrate-mongo

i am developing a nestjs application where i am using the package migrate-mongo, i have init the migrate-mongo command with
`npx migrate-mongo -m esm init`

then i had to add "type" : "module" in my package.json, also this is my migrate-mongo-config.js file

```
const config = {
  mongodb: {
    url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/persomic',
    options: {
      useNewUrlParser: true, // removes a deprecation warning when connecting
      useUnifiedTopology: true, // removes a deprecating warning when connecting
    },
  },
  migrationsDir: 'migrations',
  changelogCollectionName: 'changelog',
  migrationFileExtension: '.js',
  useFileHash: true,
  moduleSystem: 'esm',
};
export default config;
```

As far as i know migrate-mongo supports ts files from version 10.0.0, but when i add migrationFileExtension: '.ts', i get the error

`Unexpected token export`

in one of my migration file which is the following

```
export const up = async (db, client) => { };

export const down = async (db, client) => { };
```

but when i change the config to .js it works fine. Works fine creating migration files, but doesnt work when used up command

the problems i am facing right now:

1. cannot work with ts files
2. have to add type: module to src package.json which can give rise to additional problems( is there any workaround?)
3. Also no migrations collection is being created in my mongodb, but changelog(default collection name) is being created.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate using this npm library instead.

[mongoose-legacy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-legacy)

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)